# Is this a pattern or just randomized data points?

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, survival, kaplan-meier

During the research for my thesis I came across this pattern several times, it looks to me as an inverse-gamma pattern but I am not sure if I can claim that this is a pattern afterall. Let me show you some screenshots.

--**Edit**--
I cannot disclose too much about those data points, but i can answer most
of the questions in the comments.
The X axis is a timestamp of the moment of "death" of each data point
The Y axis is the score of some metric I'm researching. I want to know whether this can be thought as a pattern or this data points forming as is by blind chance.

Those triangles represent individual observations, but I have edited them too be transparent. Meaning that wherever you see a transparent triangle that's a single observation BUT in areas when you see a single triangle with solid fill there are multiple data points covering each other

We can think the X-axis as the number of seasons passed, and the Y-axis the times the subject migrated.

Now the points gathered at the end, for example the number 40 in the first dataset, are the points that actually survived till the end of our research.That is

- 40 is the end for the 1st dataset
- 10 for the 2nd
- 10 for the 3rd
- 200 for the 4th
- 200 for the 5th
- 150 for the 6th

The remaining data points mean that, at a specific season_id a subject which committed a specific number of migrations died. The purpose behind this diagram is to see if committing a certain number of migrations means the subject is going to survive. Apparently, that does not happen, so what I am searching now is if I can claim that there is a certain pattern that governs the population of each dataset.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Two comments. 1) Can you clarify what the axes and points are? 2) If there is *not* a pattern, can you expand on what you mean by "randomized data points"? The answer to this second question would be your null model, which will get you most of the way towards a statistical significance test.

Comment: Are these diamonds individual observations? counts of something? Pls tell us not just what they are but the context where they come from.

Comment: Although your added explanation helps, it does not appear to offer enough information to distinguish between a *truncated* distribution and a *censored* distribution.  They will look identical when plotted but require different methods of analysis.  You need to explain more about how it comes about that many of your observations appear to occur at some common limiting value within each dataset.

Comment: Thank you for the added explanation.  In response I have included the [tag:survival] tag: link through it to see a list of related threads.  Good search keywords are "survival analysis," "Kaplan-Meier," and "product-limit."